# Retrieve Default ACL in Python Using Posix 1e

Tags: python, acl

Using the [posix 1e Python module](http://pylibacl.k1024.org/module.html) I am able to get/set the ACL for a file without having to spawn a subprocess and call `getfacl`/`setfacl`:

```
>>> import posix1e
>>> acl1 = posix1e.ACL(file="file.txt") 
>>> print acl1
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

I can also *apply* a default ACL and *delete* it:

```
path = '/some/other/path/'
acl1.applyto(path, posix1e.ACL_TYPE_DEFAULT)
posix1e.delete_default(path)
```

However, **I can not seem to work out how to *retrieve* the default ACL**!  Does anyone know how this can be done using the posix 1e module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is a way to do this:

```
default_acl1 = posix1e.ACL(filedef="/some/other/path/")
```