# Is there any python modules that handle additional user permissions in extended ACLs as in drwxr-x---+?

Tags: python, file-permissions

I have a directory that contains the additional user bit (the 11th bit).
However, the Python's `os` or `stat` modules do not have the methods to check for any additional users permissions.

I have a file `/home/work/file_name.txt`:

```
drwxr-xr-x+  2 POUG  NEWYORK       8192 Oct 23 12:16 file_name.txt
```

I get the status of `file_name.txt` using `os.stat()`, and get the mode `stat.filemode()`.

The mode came out only as `drwxr-x-rx` without the `+` bit.

```
getfacl file_name.txt/
#file:  file_name.txt//
#owner: POUG
#group: NEWYORK
user::rwx

group::r-x

other::r-x

user:NYC:rwx
```

This is a two part question:

1. Is there a way to retrieves the + bit?
2. Is there a python module that handles `getfacl` permission bits?

   ```
   import os
   import stat

   status = os.stat('/home/work/file_name.txt')

   # retrieves permission bits in rwx form
   mode = stat.filemode(status.st_mode)      # however, this only retrieves drwxr-x-r-x

   # test dir/file, read/write/execute for owner/group/others
   stat.S_ISDIR(mode)
   bool(status.st_mode & stat.S_IREAD)
   bool(mode & stat.S_ISVTX)
   ```

   etc...

What are some methods to test additional user permissions?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a separate `+` bit.

The `ls` code knows how to retrieve the ACL set.  If it exists, and display is desired, ls uses the `+` character to mark the existence of the ACL.  See [this ServerFault article](https://serverfault.com/q/227852).

There are multiple Python ACL accessor libraries.  A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+getfacl) turned up a StackOverflow question as the second result, [Retrieve Default ACL in Python Using Posix 1e](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38855666/1256452), which refers to a `posix1e` module, which appears to be in [PyPI as pylibacl](https://pypi.org/project/pylibacl/).